# Saving collection_select with has_many through using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I setup a has_many through association with my models and I am trying to create a form where I can add multiple genres to a submitted song. I am using the collection_select helper for this. Here are snippets on how my code is setup.

Song Model

```
has_many :song_genres
has_many :genres, :through => :song_genres
```

Genre Model

```
has_many :song_genres
has_many :songs, :through => :song_genres
```

Song Genre Model

```
belongs_to :song
belongs_to :genre
```

Then in my new.html.erb
I have this

```
collection_select :song, :genres, Genre.all, :id, :name, {:selected => 1}, {:multiple => true}
```

When I submit the form I get a

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: genres
```

error

I know I'm missing something big here. Can someone help me out on how to properly set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: Full solution is in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
collection_select :song, :genre_id, Genre.all, :id, :name, {:selected => 1}, {:multiple => true}
```

As stated in the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models):
"If you are using select (or similar helpers such as collection_select, select_tag) to set a belongs_to association you must pass the name of the foreign key (in the example above city_id), not the name of association itself."

Comment: when I try that I get `undefined method 'genre_id' for #<Song:0x501efe8>` also what do I need on my controller to save these options? currently all I have is @song.save and that's it.

Comment: I'm reading again your question, how can you choose more than one genres with a select?

Comment: just setting `:multiple => true` lets me pick multiple options

Comment: I understand, I don't know how `collection_select` works in these cases. Maybe you need to use other helpers [1] in this case and then use these values in the controller manually creating the SongGenre objects.

[1]: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Comment: I have also attempted using a regular select `f.select :genres, Genre.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true` and got the same error

Comment: When you try with the regular select and replace `:genres` with `:genre_id` do you get the same error? BTW I don't know if Rails can manages multiple selection for you or you need to get these values and build the associations for your own.

Comment: Ya same thing. I also tried using check_box_tag `<% Genre.all.each do |genre| %>
        <%= genre.name %>
        <%= check_box_tag :genre_ids,
                          genre.id,
                          @song.genres.include?(genre),
                          :name => 'song[genre_id][]' %>
    <% end %>` and I get this `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: genre_id` does something need to be done with attr_accessible or something?

Comment: So I got it to work. I had to use this `<%= collection_select :song, :genre_ids, Genre.all, :id, :name, {:selected => 1}, {:multiple => true} %>` and add `attr_accessible :genre_ids` to my Song model. Thnx for the help